# Button changed to grey color for a short while after clicked in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, python-2.x

I wrote a simply GUI in mac using python tkinter. Everything is fine, except the button for opening the system file directory. The button will turn into grey rectangle for a short while after I click the button. And it will return to normal in less than 1sec.

I tried to change the button background color but I think it does not work in macOS. And I also tried to set the activebackground color to same as my frame background color, but it does not seem work as well.

Here is my code:

```
import sys, os
Path_lib = os.path.dirname(
                os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
                )
if not Path_lib in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(Path_lib)


from Tkinter import *
import ttk,platform, threading, subprocess
import datetime as dt
import tkFileDialog
import ttk

def check_dir():
    if platform.system() in ("Linux", "Darwin"):
        init_dir = "~"
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        init_dir = "C:\\"
    return init_dir

class GUI():
    def set_state(self,widgets,var):
        widgets.config(state=NORMAL if var.get() == 1 else DISABLED)

    def get_file_name(self, tabname):
        global filename, filename_2
        if tabname == "tab1":                    
            filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
                                initialdir=check_dir())
            self.file2.configure(state=NORMAL)
            self.file2.delete(0, END)
            self.file2.insert(0, filename)
            self.file2.configure(state='readonly')


    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.geometry = root.geometry("+600+200")
        self.configure = root.configure(bg=background_color)

        ##File Path Widget
        self.file = Frame(self.root, bg=background_color)
        self.file.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        Label(self.file, 
            text="All Open Today:", 
            font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold"), 
            bg=background_color,
            fg='#FA7160'
            ).pack(side=LEFT, padx=(5,5), pady= (0,10))

        self.file2 = Entry(self.file, 
                        highlightbackground=background_color,
                        state='readonly',
                        width=45)
        self.file2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, padx=(0,10), pady= (0,10))

        self.file3 = Button(
            self.file,
            text="Open", 
            command=lambda: self.get_file_name(tabname="tab1"), 
            highlightbackground=background_color,
            font=("Helvetica", 15)
            )
        self.file3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(0,10), pady= (0,10))

def main():
    global background_color, root, \
            App, filename
    filename = ""
    root = Tk()
    root.resizable(False,False)
    background_color = "#E3FFE3"
    App = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Screenshot of the greyed button

[image: Screenshot showing greyed button]

Comment: You have put in enough code in your question — it doesn't seem like the `Button` widget is the one you're talking about. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mce] others can run. BTW, the `pack()` method returns `None` which your code is assigning to the variable `self.save1_2` — although that's probably not causing the greying issue.

Comment: I have edited the code. It should work on its own. Yap, the pack() method return none. I tried without assigning to a variable, but the grey rectangle still appeared.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Mac to test it on. It seems to work OK on Windows. Since you're using Python 2.x, make sure you have the latest version of the  Tkinter module installed.

Comment: The button works fine in MAC as well (the file directory will pop up after click). It is just that the half second grey rectangle makes the GUI look laggy.